# How can I get data from the twisted.enterprise.adbapi, Not the "Deferred" object

Tags: python, sql-server, database, twisted, pymssql

When I use the twisted.enterprise.adbapi with sql_server, I always get the "Deferred" object, but I need the available data in a list or tulpe.

```
import pymssql
from twisted.internet import reactor   
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
db_settings = {
 "host" : "127.0.0.1",
 "port" : "1433",
 "user" : "sa",
 "password" : "sa",
 "database" : "dataDB",
 "cp_min" : "3",
 "cp_max" : 10,
 "cp_noisy" : "True",
 "charset" : "utf8"
}

dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("pymssql", **db_settings)

def getData():
    return dbpool.runQuery("SELECT * FORM dataDB.Base")

reactor.callLater(4, reactor.stop)
print getData()
reactor.run()
```

The above code execution，just get "Deferred at 0x4ca2948" in command. What should I do in next?

Comment: Did you read any of the documentation?  This is a very basic question about how to use Twisted.

Comment: I read the documents at "https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool.html#runQuery",  It just told me the "def runQuery(self, *args, **kw):" will return "a Deferred" like "a DB-API cursor's 'fetchall' method", but didn't tell me how to catch the data from the deferred, and no code example for ms_sql_server or other database. So I try to use Google, And no good result for this situation, If you can help me, Please, Thanks.

Comment: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it demonstrates no prior reading of the relevant project documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use follow code, Can get the data from the "Deferred"

```
def getAge():
 return dbpool.runQuery("SELECT * FROM Base")

def getValue(L):
    print L[0][0]  # type(L[0]) is Tuple

getAge().addCallback(getValue)
reactor.run()
```

But, I still don't know the meaning of "L" in function getValue. Maybe the "L" is result of getAge(), I am not sure.